# Can't login to local site (Already tried some things)

Tags: users, uri

Apache Rewrite module is working. tried using the following addresses in aim to login (I am not logged in and therefore can't enable Clean URL's):

```
localhost/Benos/?q=user/
```

Both of the addresses brings me back to localhost, and thus I kinda stuck and can't login... Why would this happen? Thx.

Comment: BTW, .HTaccess is configured for drupal, and clearing cache with Drush didn't help.

Comment: How does your setup look, exactly? Usually it should be just `http://localhost/user/` or maybe `http://localhost/?q=user/` (clean URLs aren't enabled by default?).

Comment: Sorry, I've mistakenly copied a erroneous row... My install is Localhost (Wamp). Rewrtie and Vhost both enabled, but still, not CleanUrls. It seems I need to enable them manually somehow...

Comment: You should explain your setup in more detail (apache doc root, drupal instawllation folder) to be able to help you.

Comment: Is mod_rewrite enabled? ake a look at phpinfo.

Comment: What do you see when you go to the login URL you mentioned above? Do you even see the website when you go to `http://localhost/Benos/`?

Comment: All data here:

I have a local Wamp installation. A drupal-optimized HTaccess file is in place. Apache modules: Rewrite&Vhost, are both checked, and Settings.php includes the syntax: $conf['clean_url'] = 0;.

Likewise, I've added the syntax:

I've added the following syntax to the httpd.conf:

AllowOverride All
AccessFileName .htaccess.

(With or without a hask).

Yet, When I try to enable Clean URL'S (in Drupal's configuration menu), the moment I try to enable tham I'm being transferred to Localhost\.

Comment: Do you have any modules enabled that might affect this? E.g. redirect module, or securesite?

Comment: I do have both Global Redirect, and Redirect modules...... It's interesting what you say --- Why having them is  aproblem?

Comment: Would you suggest of deleting their folders?